# NSOutlineView and isItemExpandable not working in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa

In converting a `Cocoa` app to `Swift` from `Objective-C`, I'm having a problem with the item property (type id) in the data source's `itemIsExpandable` method.

In Objective-C I test for `item==nil` and and return the number of children of the item if it isn't: `[[item children] count]` Since in Swift this property is of type `AnyObject`, I can't test for nil.

I also can't test for zero without getting an unwrapping error. I can't necessarily return a true value because in some cases the item has no children. To add to the confusion, in the data source method `numberOfChildrenOfItem` the type for item is the optional `AnyObject`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution to your problems is through Swift’s optional chaining, as seen below:

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if let _ = (item as? TreeNode)?.children {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int {

    if let children = (item as? TreeNode)?.children {
        return children.count
    }

    return content.count
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject {

    if let child = (item as? TreeNode)?.children?[index] {
        return child
    } else if index >= 0 && index != NSNotFound {
        return content[index]
    }

    return self
}
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that you’re both performing the equivalent of your Objective-C nil check as well as guarding against problems elsewhere in the chain (for example, if `item` turns out to be something other than a `TreeNode`). Generally, forced unwraps (`!`) should be avoided where possible.

Comment: It took me a while, but the optional chaining example was the one that my data model worked with the best. I went into this just thinking that the difference between Swift and Obj-C was syntax, but the last few days have made me realize that Swift is extremely powerful and requires a different way of thinking in order to use it for Cocoa apps. It's amazing. Only one "!" was necessary to get it working. Thanks! You all are amazing too.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the data-source method in question is as follows:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool
```

`item` is simply one of the objects you passed to the data source via `-outlineView(_:child:ofItem:)`, so **figure out what kind of object it is and use the object's properties to work out what you should return**. In the code below my data source is simple - everything is a `Document`:

```
class Document: NSObject {
    dynamic var title: String?
    dynamic var documents = NSMutableArray() // children
    dynamic var isPage: NSNumber! // isExpandable
    dynamic weak var parent: Document?
}
```

Here's the data-source:

```
// MARK:- NSOutlineViewDataSource

// <contents> is the array holding the top-level tree objects

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int {
    return item == nil ? contents.count : (item as! Document).documents.count
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return (item as! Document).isPage.boolValue == false
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject {
    // The object returned here is always a Document
    return item == nil ? contents[index] : (item as! Document).documents[index]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`item` is not an optional because it will never be `nil`. A `nil` item would represent the root item, but that's not visible. It's the "virtual" parent of the top-level items that are actually visible. Since it's never shown and its children are always shown, the outline view doesn't care if it's "expandable" and will never ask your delegate that.